# Selector For JSON Response Content

Tags: c#, json, linq, selector

I can't seem to find the right selector for this json result.

```
{
    "response": {
        "1017": {
            "total": {
                "inStock": 1,
                "onHand": 1,
                "allocated": 0,
                "inTransit": 0
            },
            "warehouses": {
                "3": {
                    "byLocation": {
                        "6": {
                            "inStock": 1,
                            "onHand": 1,
                            "allocated": 0,
                            "inTransit": 0
                        }
                    },
                    "inStock": 1,
                    "onHand": 1,
                    "allocated": 0,
                    "inTransit": 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to get to is the byLocation > 6 > onHand value.

I thought this would work, but does not return a value:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(response.Content);

QOH = o.SelectToken("response[0].1017[0].warehouses[0].3[0].byLocation[0].6[0].onHand").ToString();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen you are the man!  Saved my day!

Comment: @ChristophLütjen The site is a not secure one. It redirects to multiple malicious site. Kindly provide links to tools that are secure

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar - while I don't know much about jsonselector.com I can't see any links except of privacy policy and github project on this site. Could you please provide some details what makes you think this site links to malicious sites? (or if you know a better alternative, you could share the link?)

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Use https://jsonpathfinder.com/. It is https

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var QOH = o.SelectToken("response.1017.warehouses.3.byLocation.6.onHand").ToString();
```

result

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [querying JSON with SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm)
also without specifying the full path

```
o.SelectToken("$..byLocation..onHand")?.ToString()

o.SelectToken("$..byLocation.*.onHand")?.ToString()

o.SelectToken("$..byLocation.6.onHand")?.ToString()

o.SelectToken("$..warehouses.*.byLocation.*.onHand")?.ToString()
```